# How to stick to block with CSS

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a very simple code in HTML/CSS in which I just want to stick the 2 first blocks named header1 in blue and header2 in red. I would like that the 2 blocks are stuck with no white space between them.

Here is the code :

```css
/* style22.css */


/* Définition des caractéristiques globales */

body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  / color: #FFF;
}


/* Header */

#conteneur {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header1 {
  background: blue;
}


/* Navigation */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header id="conteneur">

  <div class="header1">
    <div><a href="how.html"><span class="logo">ALGOBETTER</span></a></div>
  </div>

  <nav class="header2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="gold_rules.html">Règles d'or</a></li>
      <li><a href="pronos.html">Pronostics</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Maybe you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your white space is caused by the default margin of the `ul` of your `.header2`. Simply add `nav ul { margin: 0; }` to remove the whitespace.

```css
/* style22.css */


/* Définition des caractéristiques globales */

body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  / color: #FFF;
}


/* Header */

#conteneur {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header1 {
  background: blue;
}


/* Navigation */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header id="conteneur">

  <div class="header1">
    <div><a href="how.html"><span class="logo">ALGOBETTER</span></a></div>
  </div>

  <nav class="header2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="gold_rules.html">Règles d'or</a></li>
      <li><a href="pronos.html">Pronostics</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `margin: 0;` to the ul (unordered lists have margins *different from 0* by default):

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Header */

#conteneur {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header1 {
  background: blue;
}


/* Navigation */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header1">
  <div><a href="how.html"><span class="logo">ALGOBETTER</span></a></div>
</div>

<nav class="header2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="gold_rules.html">Règles d'or</a></li>
    <li><a href="pronos.html">Pronostics</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your css try:

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Comment: @tacoshy I am trying to help here, you can do everything you mentioned if you have a solution, I am not a high school teacher to explain everything here

Comment: @tacoshy I would try helping others rather targeting someone for not reading guidelines, please provide the correct solution if you have otherwise you are welcome to leave :)